# Square Integrable for Fourier Transform

Tags: options, option-pricing

The FFT paper for Option Pricing by Carr and Madan says that the reason for adding a dampener to the call price function is because it is not square-integrable: when the log of strike goes to -infinity, the call price goes to S0. I agree with this but I thought that the square integrable property meant that the integral of square of a function between -+ infinity is finite. So, I have 2 questions:

(1) How does the call price function break the square integrable property?

(2) If the call price is not square integrable why can't we take it's Fourier Transform?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A real-valued function $f(x)$ is *square integrable* over $\Bbb{R}$, we write $f \in L^2(\Bbb{R})$, if and only if
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x)^2 dx < \infty \tag{1} $$
A *necessary condition* for the above integral to be finite is $$\lim_{\vert x \vert\to\infty} f(x) = 0$$
To convince yourself, think of the interpretation of an integral as the area under a curve: what do you think happens to the integral $(1)$ when $f(x)$ tends to a non-zero asymptotic limit, knowing that the integrand $f(x)^2$ is positive everywhere?

Let $C(k,T)$ denote the price (as of today) of a European call option, expiring at $T$ and struck at $K=e^k$. Since $$\lim_{k\to-\infty} C(k,T) = \lim_{k\to-\infty} \Bbb{E}^\Bbb{Q}_t \left[ (S_T - e^k)^+ B_T^{-1} \right] = B(0,T) F(0,T) \ne 0$$ 
we have that $C(k,T) \notin L^2$ which answers your first question.

---

Your second question is more technical. Basically, you are facing a situation where the risk-neutral pdf associated to your diffusion framework is not *analytically tractable*, so that you cannot evaluate the expression
$$ C(k,T) = \Bbb{E}^\Bbb{Q}_t \left[ (S_T - e^k)^+ B_T^{-1} \right]  = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} (e^{s_T}-e^k)^+ B_T^{-1} \phi(T, s_T) ds_T $$

Still, your model being *affine*, you know that you can identify the *characteristic function* of $s_T=\ln(S_T)$ in closed-form, which happens to be the Fourier transform of the pdf $\phi(T,s_T)$:
$$\mathcal{G}_g(u) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{ius} \phi(T,s) ds$$

From there you would like to appeal to a result known as the *Parseval relation*, which would allow you to write
\begin{align}
C(k,T) &= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \underbrace{(e^{s_T}-e^k)^+ B_T^{-1}}_{f(s_T)} \underbrace{\phi(T, s_T)}_{g(s_T)} ds_T \\
& = \langle f(s_T), g(s_T) \rangle = \frac{1}{2\pi}\langle \mathcal{F}_f(u), \mathcal{G}_g(u) \rangle \tag{Parseval} \\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \mathcal{F}_f(u) \mathcal{G}_g(u) du
\end{align}
which would allow you to exploit your knowledge of the characteristic function $\mathcal{G}_g(u)$: you just need to find the Fourier transform of the discounted payoff. This is exactly what @MJ73550 did in his answer.

The thing is that the Parseval relationship only holds for functions of $f$ and $g$ in $L^2$. Using a similar argument as above it is easy to see that $f \notin L^2$

Comment: Thank you Quantuple for the detailed answer. My second question was slightly different actually. It was related to the fact that we add a dampener to the C(k,T) (exp(-alpha k) for atm options and 1/sinh(alpha k) for otm before fourier transform) because C(k,T) is not square integrable. But actually your first answer pointed to the necessary condition which I had missed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

$$E\left[(e^{X_T}-K)^+\right]=E\left[e^{\lambda X_T}e^{-\lambda X_t}(e^{X_T}-K)^+\right]$$
for $\lambda>1$ it is ok to take the fourier transform of $e^{-\lambda x}(e^{x}-K)^+$. Let $\hat{f}_{\lambda,k}$ be the fourier transform of $e^{-\lambda x}(e^{x}-K)^+$ then you get:

$$E\left[(e^{X_T}-K)^+\right] = \int_{\mathbb{R}}E\left[e^{(\lambda +i2\pi\xi) X_T}\hat{f}_{\lambda,k}(\xi)\right]d\xi$$
and then you use Fourier transfrom pricing because you know well how to compute $\phi_{T}(u)=E[e^{u X_T}]$ thus,
$$E\left[(e^{X_T}-K)^+\right] = \int_{\mathbb{R}}\phi_T\left(\lambda +i2\pi\xi\right)\hat{f}_{\lambda,k}(\xi)d\xi$$